# Login Through Facebook Feature available for ios10?

Tags: swift, facebook, authentication, ios10

I was looking into xcode8 beta and ios10 and was looking into a login with Twitter or login with Facebook button.  From the reading i've done,  the login with twitter button (fabric)  doesnt support ios10 yet.  I was wondering if Facebook supports ios10 yet for the login button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it does not (although it may still work).

See the official [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-4.x).